# Custom RoleProvider not working when deployed to web app's bin directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, membership-provider, roleprovider

I have created custom membership and role providers for a SharePoint web application.

If I deploy the DLL for these classes into the GAC, the membership/role provision works just fine.  If I deploy these DLLs to the web application's bin folder in IIS, the web app bails with a server error immediately when browsing to the site.

> Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

If I view source on the error page I get a bit more info:

> [ConfigurationErrorsException]: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\theportal.com80\web.config line 119)
>      at System.Web.Security.Roles.Initialize()
>      at System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

The line it is referring to is:

```
<add name="PortalRoleProvider" applicationName="/" 
     type="Portal.Security.PortalRoleProvider, 
           Portal.Security, Version=1.1.0.0, 
           Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=5be544eaa65820dd" 
/>
```

It must be a **permissions thing**, because as I say there is no error if deployed to the GAC -- and furthermore, there are no errors if I set the web app's web.config up with full trust.

```
<trust level="full" />
```

I have added **CAS policies** (well, WSPBuilder has added them automatically for me.)  They don't seem to be working though. They are as follows for the DLL that houses the role provider:

```
<PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Description="WSPBuilder generated permissionSet" Name="portal.shareddllsinstaller.wsp-3a7ba544-2178-4505-a9d9-28622c565d07-1">
    <IPermission class="AspNetHostingPermission" version="1" Level="Medium" />
    <IPermission class="SecurityPermission" version="1" Flags="Assertion, Execution, ControlThread, ControlPrincipal, RemotingConfiguration" />
    <IPermission class="SharePointPermission" version="1" ObjectModel="True" />
    <IPermission class="EnvironmentPermission" version="1" Read="TEMP;TMP;USERNAME;OS;COMPUTERNAME" />
    <IPermission class="PrintingPermission" version="1" Level="DefaultPrinting" />
    <IPermission class="WebPartPermission" version="1" Connections="True" />
    <IPermission class="FileIOPermission" version="1" Read="$AppDir$" Write="$AppDir$" Append="$AppDir$" PathDiscovery="$AppDir$" />
    <IPermission class="WebPermission" version="1">
        <ConnectAccess>
            <URI uri="$OriginHost$" />
        </ConnectAccess>
    </IPermission>
    <IPermission class="IsolatedStorageFilePermission" version="1" Allowed="AssemblyIsolationByUser" UserQuota="9223372036854775807" />
    <IPermission class="DnsPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
    <IPermission class="SmtpPermission" version="1" Access="Connect" />
    <IPermission class="SqlClientPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
</PermissionSet>
```

Any ideas how to get these custom role/membership providers to work in the bin dir?  What might be causing them to fail?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a wild guess, but perhaps: is your application-root a few levels down? i.e.

```
http://foo.com/MyApp
http://foo.com/bar/MyApp
```

instead of

```
http://foo.com/
```

? If so, you need to ensure that IIS knows to consider `/MyApp` / `/bar/MyApp` the app-root, by clicking "create application" in IIS (it'll get a bog icon).

Essentially, `~/bin` is relative to the app-root, which is *by default* the site-root. So even though your code is at `/bar/MyApp`, it is looking for the dll in `/bin/some.dll`. By correctly marking the application root, it will look for `/bar/MyApp/bin/some.dll`.

Comment: Thanks yes the app root is the site root (as far as I understand, anyway -- entirely possible SP is doing some shenanigans behind the scenes that I don't know of...)  The providers work if I set trust to Full in web.config though, so I guess it can find the DLL at least?